# Serving django application via apache and development server results different character encoding

Tags: python-3.x, django, apache2.4

I've the following setup:
Django: 4.0.5
Python: 3.9.2
Debian: 11.1
Apache2: 2.4.53-1~deb11u1
libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3: 4.7.1-3+b1
mariadb-server-10.5: 1:10.5.15-0+deb11u1
.

When I run my application from the development server (same virtualenv, same code), it runs without any error, but when I run the same via apache2, it throws some kind of encoding error here:

```
strx = 'sth %s' % name
f = open('/tmp/somerandomfile', 'w')
f.write(strx)
```

. The name variable is coming from the database and contains a national character.

When I print it via the development server and apache2, I got these:

```
#development server - to the console
print(strx, type(strx))
Kiadások <class 'str'>

#apache2 - to the apache log file
print(strx, type(strx))
Kiad\xc3\xa1sok <class 'str'>
```

. So it seems the 2 str differs in encoding.

The development server serves with 200, however, apache2 serve fails with the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\\xe1' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

To fix it's easy, however, I'm rather interested why do I get a different result via the development server and apache2? How can I set it to have the same result.

As mentioned, I'm using wsgi.

Any idea where I could check for differences? And how could I have the exact same behaviour on Apache2 server and the the django development server?

Thanks.

---

***UPDATE***

Listing the locals() I can see this difference:

```
#development server
'f': <_io.TextIOWrapper name='/tmp/tmplnrhh7np' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>

#apache2 log
'f': <_io.TextIOWrapper name='/tmp/tmpw3jl3sk2' mode='w' encoding='ANSI_X3.4-1968'>
```

. So apache2 - at least for file creation - uses some ANSI_X3.4-1968 encoding whatever it's. How can I make apache to use the same UTF-8 encoding as well?

My related apache2 config files:

```
#sites-enabled/gyuser.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName 127.0.0.25
ServerAlias Servernames
DocumentRoot /usr/share/gyuser

<Directory /usr/share/gyuser>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess gyuser.djangoserver user=gyuser processes=10 threads=20 display-name=%{GROUP} python-path=/usr/share/gyuser:/home/gyuser/.virtualenvs/gyuser/lib/python3.9/site-packages

WSGIProcessGroup gyuser.djangoserver

WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/share/gyuser/gyuser/wsgi.py
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/gyuser-access.log combined
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/gyuser-error.log
LogLevel debug
```

```
#wsgi.py
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "gyuser.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Sorry I don't have an answer but have a question of my own which I posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73263626/django-served-with-apache-how-to-set-pythonpath and got no responces. Hope someone may take a look and be able to suggest something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it's worth to check the result of the sys.getfilesystemencoding() .

On apache2 it results ascii to me, on dev server it results utf-8 .

So, to solve the problem, You need to add something like that to /etc/apache2/envvars:

```
export LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
export LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'
```

. That should do the trick on debian.

Link to similar problem:

https://groups.google.com/g/modwsgi/c/MRsMc9yehBI?pli=1

.